# Analyzing the free-particle kernel

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, path-integral

I recently began studying the theory of path integrals from the book by Feynman and Hibbs.

> The Problem $3.6$ asks to give an argument to show that $F(t_b,t_a)$ depends only on $t_b-t_a$.

Referring to the Equations $(3.44)$, $(3.50)$ and $(3.51)$, it can be said that for a free-particle, $$F(t_b,t_a)=\int^{0}_{0}{e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\int^{t_b}_{t_a} \frac{1}{2} m\dot{y}^2 dt} \mathscr{D} y(t)}$$

However, I'm not being able to predict the possible argument behind the expected behavior of the function $F(t_b,t_a)$. I don't think that the reasoning could be derived by further simplifying the integral, but that it should be related to the presence of $\frac{1}{(t_b-t_a)}$ in the adjoining factor $e^{\frac{im}{2\hbar}\frac{(x_b-x_1)^2}{(t_b-t_a)}}$ of the kernel.

Comment: Hint: There is no _explicit_ time dependence in the Lagrangian, so how could the physical amplitude overlap depend on other time parameters than the elapsed time $t_b-t_a$?